# Operador de JavaScript similar a SQL "not like"

Tags: javascript

**Hola amigos quisiera realizar la misma operación que nos permite SQL con (NOT LIKE), pero en JavaScript**

*Vi que con la función match se puede obtener la misma operación SQL (LIKE)*

```js
var datos = [{'c_cuent':'101111','l_cuent':'cuenta 1'},{'c_cuent':'101111','l_cuent':'cuenta 2'},{'c_cuent':'121111','l_cuent':'cuenta 3'}];

console.log(datos.filter(d => (d.c_cuent).match(/101.*/)));
```

**LO QUE DESEO ES REALIZAR LA MISMA OPERACION PERO CON (NOT LIKE)**

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar el negado de tu función actual

```
datos.filter(d => !(d.c_cuent).match(/101.*/))
```